# Run Two Instances Of vlc At The Same Time

Tags: bash

Hello I Am Trying To Run Two Instances Of vlc at the same time using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

vlc http://testvideo1.com/video.mp4

vlc http://testvideo1.com/video.m3u8
```

but when i run this the second command will not run until i close the first instance of vlc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a script will wait for each command until the process returns. (i.e. closes) You should use the [ampersand](http://hacktux.com/bash/ampersand) operator to run the commands in the background. Your bash script should read:

```
#!/bin/bash

vlc http://testvideo1.com/video.mp4 &
vlc http://testvideo1.com/video.m3u8 &
```

Comment: If you want your script to exit only when all the processes are closed, you can use wait. One simple way of doing it would be `wait %1; wait %2`